# Textbox and messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus, messagebox

I have 2 input box on my form. If user enter data he can press enter to see if they are correct or in the other case messagebox will appear with error. Now i have small problem. When messagebox appears and user presses enter, msgbox disappear and immediately appear another one. I wanted to disappear, and let user change their data. How can i fix that?
 I tried to fix that in that way: i added invisible textbox, when user press enter this textbox gains focus, if there is error msgbox appears and in the end sender gains focus.
code:

```
private void login(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        focus.Focus();
        if (password.Password == "" || account.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Fill login and password.");
        }
        if(sender.GetType() == account.GetType())
          ((TextBox)sender).Focus();
        else
          ((PasswordBox)sender).Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use WPF validation (IDataErrorInfo etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **e.Handled = true;** to prevent propagating of the key press to your text box.

Comment: I tried to past it on the top of login method, after i know that enter was pressed, after msgbox appeared. Did i something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPass.Text))
        {
            if (1 + 1 != 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong!!!");
                txtPass.Clear();
                txtPass.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It works, but i need way to don't clear input boxes. Maybe i will add red label with errors instead of messagebox, but it's not good way.